# Generating photo quality scans with WIA in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, epson, wia

So I have been working on updates to a fairly simple and task-specific image processing app that I rolled out some time ago.  Due to a tendency of the imaging techs who use this software to mess with their scanner settings in ways that require the program to accommodate unnecessary changes, sometimes intentionally and sometimes accidentally, I wanted to add a Scan button in the update that will standardize things like image resolution and color settings in order to enforce uniformity while also reducing the number of programs employees have to have open and switch between.  Initially I tried to accomplish this with a Powershell script that was called by the original python program.  That was a nightmare, is *not* what I am doing now, and this is *not* a duplicate of the question I posted with regards to that problem.  So, on to the problem:

Rather than sticking with python and Powershell, I wrote the upgraded app in C#, using WIA to handle the scanner and Aforge.Net to perform image post-processing tasks. I have code that works reasonably well, finds the scanner, and scans the image in color with the appropriate size, resolution, and compression.  The issue is that this is still not really a "photo-quality" image.  We are scanning comic books and things like smudges and creases in the cover have to be visible on all scans, even very dark ones.  The Epson scan manager accomplishes this pretty well, though it washes out the images a bit in the process, but I can't figure out what settings I should change in order to achieve a similar end.  As an example, here is a test image scanned with the scan button on my app:
[image: My Scan Button]

And here is the same image scanned using the Epson Scan Manager:
[image: Epson Scan Manager]

I basically want to know how I get the top image to look more like the bottom image.  It doesn't have to be exactly the same, but I need to be able to see all those smudges and imperfections, or at least as many of them as possible.  I can pretty easily imitate the general look of the bottom image with image filters, but I can't use that to get information that the scanner didn't get.  Post-processing won't necessarily get me those smudges back.  I need to adjust how the image is taken.  In theory, I know I should be able to play with something like exposure times and the like but I can't even find appropriate constants for that sort of thing as the documentation is somewhat opaque.  Here is the code I currently have for accessing the scanner and getting the scan:

```
private static void AdjustScannerSettings(IItem scannerItem, int scanResolutionDPI, int scanStartLeftPixel, int scanStartTopPixel, int scanWidthPixels, int scanHeightPixels, int brightnessPercents, int contrastPercents, int colorMode)
{
    const string WIA_SCAN_COLOR_MODE = "6146";
    const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6147";
    const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6148";
    const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6149";
    const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6150";
    const string WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6151";
    const string WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6152";
    const string WIA_SCAN_BRIGHTNESS_PERCENTS = "6154";
    const string WIA_SCAN_CONTRAST_PERCENTS = "6155";
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, "4104", 24);
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI, scanResolutionDPI);
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI, scanResolutionDPI);
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL, scanStartLeftPixel);
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL, scanStartTopPixel);
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS, scanWidthPixels);
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS, scanHeightPixels);
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_BRIGHTNESS_PERCENTS, brightnessPercents);
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_CONTRAST_PERCENTS, contrastPercents);
    SetWIAProperty(scannerItem.Properties, WIA_SCAN_COLOR_MODE, colorMode);
}
private static void SetWIAProperty(IProperties properties, object propName, object propValue)
{
    Property prop = properties.get_Item(ref propName);
    prop.set_Value(ref propValue);
}
private void buttonScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var deviceManager = new DeviceManager();
    DeviceInfo firstScannerAvailable = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Count; i++)
    {
        if (deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i].Type != WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
        {
            continue;
        }
        firstScannerAvailable = deviceManager.DeviceInfos[i];
        break;
    }
    var device = firstScannerAvailable.Connect();
    var scannerItem = device.Items[1];
    int resolution = 300;
    int width_pixel = 3510;
    int height_pixel = 5100;
    int color_mode = 1;
    AdjustScannerSettings(scannerItem, resolution, 0, 0, width_pixel, height_pixel, 0, 0, color_mode);

    var imageFile = (ImageFile)scannerItem.Transfer("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}");

    var pathbase = Path.Combine(pictures, basedaemonpath);
    string filebase = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss-fffffff") + ".jpg";
    var path = Path.Combine(pathbase, filebase);

    WIA.ImageProcess myip = new WIA.ImageProcess();  // use to compress jpeg.
    myip.Filters.Add(myip.FilterInfos["Convert"].FilterID);
    myip.Filters[1].Properties["FormatID"].set_Value("{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}");
    myip.Filters[1].Properties["Quality"].set_Value(84);

    ImageFile image = myip.Apply(imageFile);

    image.SaveFile(path);
}
```

I can include the post-processing code as well if it is needed but there is a *lot* of it (It is the primary function of the app after all) and all it really does is get a bunch of information about the content of the image and then rotate and crop it.  It shouldn't have an effect on actual look of the image with the exception of the rotation and crop, so I'm leaving this part out for now.  If snippets of this code are necessary let me know and I will post them.  Thanks for any help you might be able to provide!

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrease the contrast and increase the brightness to get the expected results.

According to this [Microsoft WIA page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wia/-wia-wiaitempropscanneritem). The valid ranges are from -1000 to 1000.

Make the following adjustments to the `buttonScan_Click` method:

```
// ...
int width_pixel = 3510;
int height_pixel = 5100;
int color_mode = 1;
// Add the following two lines 
int brightness = 500;
int contrast = -500;
//  Change the 0, 0 to brightness, contrast in the next line.
AdjustScannerSettings(scannerItem, resolution, 0, 0, width_pixel, height_pixel, brightness, contrast, color_mode);
```

You will have to adjust the values according to the results.

Comment: Changing the brightness and contrast has no effect on the presence of cover imperfections in the image.  This is one of the first things I tried.  It looks exactly the same as the dark image, just brighter.  I think that something related to the scanner light itself needs to be adjusted but am not sure.  At any rate, changing the brightness won't help.  I need it to see the white smudges that are actually there as it is scanning, not add uniform brightness during post processing.

Comment: @Jeremiah The brightness values set are on the hardware(adjusting the light in the scanner, see `WIA_IPS_BRIGHTNESS` in the link provided), using the above code, not in post processing. The Epson software appears to be using gamma correction which is not implemented in WIA.

Comment: Well either way it doesn't work.  Again, fiddling with the brightness is literally the first thing I tried.